Как привязать к DatePicker x:Name="textBoxDate" данные с таблицы
А именно задача стоит подтянуть в календарь только даты мастеров из табеля. WPF C#.
<DatePicker x:Name="textBoxDate" SelectedDateChanged="textBoxDate_TextChanged"
SelectedDate = "{Binding MastSchedule}"/>

Хочу привязать к таблице MastSchedule колонку Date в DatePicker x:Name="textBoxDate", что бы активные были только даты из табеля.

Ничего не понял. Если ваша цель, это ограничить выбор дат, то это делается так.

@EvgeniyZ есть табель работы мастеров, там есть колонка дата, вот ее хочу подтянуть в форму записи в DatePicker и что бы даты выделялись, т.е. было видно на календаре

@EvgeniyZ в примере, что Вы мне скинули, суть такая же, только надо что бы даты были активными

Ну так вперед, привязывайте нужное свойство в нужном месте) Пример выше я показал, там есть и обычная привязка, и привязка "плохих дат".

@EvgeniyZ да, спасибо, уже разобралась, принцип тот же, просто сразу не сообразила. Буду пробовать)))
